# 2010 to 2013 Site Collection not available after migration

Tags: 2010, 2013, content-migration

I need to move a single site collection from SharePoint 2010 to an existing SharePoint 2013 farm.  The existing SharePoint 2013 farm already has most service applications configured.  Therefore, I am only trying to move the content database of the site collection from SharePoint 2010 to 2013.

I was able to attach it to our 2012 SQL Server instance without any problems.  After creating a classic-authentication based web application (I am not able to convert the 2010 site collection), I used `Test-SPContentDatabase` to check for errors.  The only errors present were missing web parts.  We are only interested in existing documents and possibly reports on the site collection; they will eventually be moved to already-existing sites on the 2013 farm.

After using `Mount-SPContentDatabase`, the site collection was created in the class-authentication web application, but it is not accessible through the browser.  It exists, as I can use PowerShell to grab a reference to it, but any attempt to browse to it results in a connection error.

Google doesn't seem to be helping -- most upgrade sites assume that the site collection will be available after the mount upgrade.  What can I do to access the site and finish the migration?

Comment: could you please share the complete error sreen shot and also check the ULS logs and share the logs if possible. so that we give you some anwser.

Comment: you should include your webparts otherwise it will give error in browser with correlation id

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff382638(v=office.15).aspx